# String comparison not working as intended. I want to compare two String values but the comparison always seems to give a true result

Tags: java, android, string, android-sqlite

I am fetching column values from my DB (Which is working fine) then I am putting these values into 'String X' one at a time as it loops. In the same loop I want to compare the values supplied to me by the user through UI with X and based on this comparison I want x to be true or false. But x always shows true! Here is my code:

```
   private boolean fillData() {
       Cursor c = DBHelper.fetchAllIDs();
       // List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
       if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String X = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IDno")));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" +X, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String B = null; 
            B = Idno.getText().toString();
            if (B.equals(X));
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "If condition true"+B, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                x=true;
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());


       }
    return x;
  }
```

Comment: i think you set default value of x is true

Comment: No I have declared x as false at the beginning.

Comment: declare x as a local variable, if it is global it will keep its previous value. also break after x = true.

Comment: Tried but x still shows true! The if condition is always getting executed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this folks, I had mistakenly put a ';' at the end of my if statement. Sorry! Silly!

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the value of

```
String X = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IDno")));
```

such as Sop(x) or inside log.

and same way print the value of

```
 B = Idno.getText().toString();
```

Sop(B) or inside log(B).

It may be both are same in meaning but different in present (case sensitive).

use

```
if(B.equalsIgnoreCase(X))
{
}
```

instead of `if (B.equals(X));`

don't put the `condition termination symbol` such as `;` at end of if statement.

Comment: Thanks you mate, I figured that out thanks to the break; statement idea of auselen